# UICollectionView Custom Layout With A Single Cell In View

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to make an application that only has one row of cells in a UICollectionView, however I'm using the FlowLayout and that stacks cells as seen below.

[image]

I want to make it something like this. Where the user can swipe left or right to get to the next cell. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Check out this tutorial: [Paging with Collection Views](http://mobileappdev.learningtree.com/2012/12/13/paging-with-collection-views-part-1/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do 3 things : 
Set the FlowLayout to scroll horizontally, enable paging, and set the size of your cell to take the whole space.
All this can be done in a nib file in the settings of the CollectionView : (CollectionView - ScrollDirection, ScrollView - paging enabled, and CollectionViewSize - Cell Size/Height).

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I wanted to make it for the iPhone I'm assuming it would have to be 320 width for the cell size?

Comment: 320x460 yes, basically the whole size of your screen (minus the status bar or any other view that reduces it)